# Need lambda to run for X times

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

Basically, it is possible to iterate the code below inside the lambda with an iterative function?

Or you need to call the lambda externally by other lambda for X times?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var connect = new AWS.Connect();

// main entry to the flow

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    //define parameter values to use in initiating the outbound call

    var params = {
        ContactFlowId: "dac29dad-35f6-4aaa-a8e5-092e5cf508fc",
        DestinationPhoneNumber: "+1716xxxxxx",
        InstanceId: "cf9b7ee2-f2b7-41ee-9791-8f33424a31aa",
        QueueId: "5838aee4-9c7d-460b-8398-4da01be6e0ec",
        Attributes: {"Name": "MyAttribute"},
        SourcePhoneNumber: "+183xxxxxx"
    };
    
    // method used to initiate the outbound call from Amazon Connect
    connect.startOutboundVoiceContact(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack) ;
        else console.log(data);
    });

    callback(null, event);
    
};
```

The function basically uses the startOutboundVoiceContact API to place an outbound call to the number you specify. I need to demonstrate that it can place X amount of calls in X amount of minutes, for that i need to run the code several times every 1 sec aprox.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AWS Step Functions to meet this requirement. Use the Map state to call an AWS Lambda function multiple times, based on the state machine input.
Here's the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-creating-map-state-machine.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you i'm gonna give it a try and post back here the results